# What workarounds exist for the `complete` property in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am attempting to use jQuery to determine if an image has properly loaded.

The following works just fine (and returns `true` or `false` as of the state of the image) but only seems to work in IE, in FireFox, it seems to always return `true` - even if the state is actually incomplete:

```
    var image = $("img#myImage");
    alert(image[0].complete);
```

What is the Firefox equivalent for `image.complete` in JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

You could also try checking one of the dimensions of the `img` element in addition to `complete`:

```
function isImageLoaded() {
    var theImage = $('#myImage'); 

    if (!theImage.get(0).complete) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (theImage.height() === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

An unloaded `img` or an `img` with an invalid `src` attribute should have `.height()` and `.width()` equal to `0` in Firefox.  In Chrome and Opera neither method appears to work properly.  In those browsers `theImage.height()` always returned a positive value in my testing.

Comment: I would think so too; but one of the examples I need to account for is as follows: One of the possible images this applies to resides on Amazon's cloud front, and if the security settings are such that the file exists, but access is denied; then it actually returns some XML content to that call, which the browser is returning a height of 15 and a width of 60. (or similar arbitrary values)

Comment: Interesting...I'll post again if I come across a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery makes it really simple.

You can just use the .load() function to bind an event for the time when image is completely loaded.

```
    $("img").load(function() {
        // Yeay, it was loaded, and works in all browsers!
    });
```

Comment: if the image was cached, IE8 will not fire the load event. See this blogpost by David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event

Comment: The above comment goes for MS Edge as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use load() but beware of Internet Explorer: It won't fire the event, if the image is cached

```
if($img[0].readyState === 4){ // image is cached in IE
    alert("Image loaded!");
}else{
    $img.load(function(){ // for other browsers and IE, if not cached
        alert("Image loaded!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was just working on an AJAX page that dynamically loaded images.  I also wanted to detect if images were loaded so I could transition them in with a jQuery effect.

```
img = $('myImageID')
img[0].src = 'http://new.url.for.image/';
alert(img[0].complete);                    // seems to always return true
                                           // in Firefox, perhaps because
                                           // the original src had been loaded
```

So instead I had to do this...

```
img = $('myImageID')
newImg = $('<img>')                // create a completely new IMG element
          .attr('src', 'http://new.url.for.image/')
          .attr('id', img[0].id);
img.replaceWith(newImg);
img = newImg;
alert(img[0].complete);
```

*(Note: I haven't tested this exact code, it's a simplified version of what I was trying to do, but hopefully communicates the idea.)*

**Simon.**

Answer (score 0):

```
myimage=new Image();
myimage.src="whatever";
if(myimage.height>0 && myimage.complete){alert("my image has loaded");}

// might be overly simple but works for me in all browsers i think.
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if firefox has another prop, method that does it but, you can use this workaround:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("img").each(
//for each image declared in html
function(index)
{
    document.images[index].complete= false;
    document.images[index].onload = function(){ this.complete= true};
});
```

});

Comment: You can't set the complete property of an image. It will throw an error because the property is read only.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I use the method

```
document.images['XXX'].addEventListener('load', dealJob(), false);
```

and in function dealJob, I use document.images['XXX'].complete to check the image, but it always returns true.

When I change to use the method

```
document.images['XXX'].onload = function() {dealJob();}
```

and in function dealJob, the result of document.images['XXX'].complete is correct.

Maybe it can help you.