# How exactly does an image element's `complete` property work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have ran into a bit of a problem with my understanding of the [`complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement#DOM_properties) property.

I assumed `complete` would be `true` if the image has been downloaded and decoded correctly.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement#DOM_properties)...

> True if the browser has fetched the image, and it is in a [supported image type](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Img#Image_Format) that was decoded without errors.

So, I assumed that checking an image's `complete` property before its `load` event had fired would return `false` (the image has not been *fetched*). When isolating this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/KKnFJ/), I kept getting `true` when checking the property inside a `script` element just before the closing `</body>` tag.

I also [experimented](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zXcK6/) with changing the `src` attribute of the image and then immediately checking its `complete` property. I can see in the browser the `complete` is coming back as `true` even before the image has downloaded (I am looking at its progress via the *Net* panel in Firebug).

Is the behaviour I am expecting correct? Is there a way to get this to work as I expect?

Currently testing in Firefox 7.0.1. This may be a Firefox bug, but only have this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268557/javascript-image-complete-what-to-use-in-firefox) as evidence.

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28832 bug report filed for Safari - are you testing it on that? Your demo results in the expected `false, false, true` on Chrome 15, at least.

Comment: @minitech: I am testing in Firefox 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer, but you're not going to like it...

When the image in question is created with `document.createElement`, it works. See http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/nmuQ8/

I discovered that this works while creating a test to see if it *doesn't* work, so so far I don't have a way to tell if the replacement is actually necessary, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 works, very interesting. I might hang out to see if a better solution comes along though :)

Answer (score 8):

From the [**w3c-docs**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/embedded-content-1.html#dom-img-complete)

> The IDL attribute complete must return true if any of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The src attribute is omitted.
> - The src attribute's value is the    empty string.
> - **The final task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been fetched has been queued, but has not yet    been
>     run, and the img element is not in the broken state.**
> - The img    element is completely available.

Sounds like the result  is correct. 
Assuming the inital image is cached, then the image already has been fetched.
It doesn't have any effect to the complete-property when you change the `src`(queue another task)

I played around a little bit and it looks as if   you get the expected result when you remove the src-attribute before setting the new src. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/UNEF7/

**Explanation:** When no src-attribute is present the state of the image turns to "broken"(the 3rd condition will not match anymore) and it will not be complete before the new ressource has been loaded.

Comment: +1 for linking to the W3C spec. Note that the W3C spec you link to is currently a draft, hence it is still changing. As a result I guess, the 3rd point you mention is now "just" saying `"The final task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been fetched has been queued."` and there is now an additional point that says `"The img element is broken."`

Comment: By the way, can someone explain that sentence from the spec `"The final task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been fetched has been queued."` ?