# Why Image 'complete' property always return true even if there is no src tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer-11

I just write

```
document.createElement("img").complete;//To check whether image is loaded or not
```

In Firefox,it returns true. In IE,it return false

OR

In a html page just create one image as:

```
 <!-- IMG tag with no SRC attribute. -->
<img id="noSrcImg" />
```

and In js check the complete property value :

```
var img = document.getElementById("noSrcImg");
img.complete
```

true for FF and false for IE

Can any one explain why this inconsistent behavior?

Is there any other better way to check whether image is loaded or not in DOM?

i tried with readyState attribute as well but its not available for IE11.

Comment: use load/error events to verify wether image is loaded correctly

Comment: some explanations here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031886/how-exactly-does-an-image-elements-complete-property-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try load

Also make sure the event handlers are defined BEFORE you assign src - on really fast networks, the src may load before the event handler if not defined first

```
var im = document.createElement("img");
im.onload=function() { alert(this.src+' loaded')} // assign before src
im.onerror=function() { alert(this.src+' failed')} // if necessary
im.src="someimage.jpg";
```

Comment: Got the answer of second question,Thanks @mplugjan but still looking for my 1st ques why such behavior?

Comment: @ThalisK. `im.onerror=function() { alert(this.src+' failed')}`

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I deleted the comment. It was: "Worth mentioning that the alert will show if image loads correctly i.e. `onload` event will not fire if `im.src` is invalid".

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in IE.  [According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-complete):

> The IDL attribute `complete` must return true if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The `src` attribute is omitted.
> - The final task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been fetched has been queued.
> - The `img` element is completely available.
> - The `img` element is broken.
>
> Otherwise, the attribute must return false.

The best way to know the state of an image, is to handle the `load` and `error` events.  If that isn't feasible, for whatever reason, to tell if an image has loaded successfully, check for `img.complete && img.naturalWidth > 0`.  If true, the image has loaded successfully.  Otherwise, the image is either still loading, or has failed to load - it's difficult to tell which because of IE's inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has finished fetching the image, whether successful or not. It also shows true, if the image has no src value.

Answer (score 0):

Empty img src like any href as a relative URL refers to a base URL, the URL of the document.
@mplungjan posted good solution to actually check if and when it was loaded