# Scroll to the bottom of the page after creating an element

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll automatically to the bottom of the page but when I run the code below it doesn't scrolls completely

```
function createElement1() {

    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "myImg");
    x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "img");
    document.getElementById("id").appendChild(x);

    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

I also tried

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
```

I use Chrome

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `element.scrollTop` is a read-only property and cannot be assigned: you will need to use `window.scrollTo()`. The issue that it doesn't scroll completely is because the body scrollHeight would have changed after the image is loaded. You will need to trigger scrolling *after* the image has loaded to get the accurate body scrollHeight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: the reason why the scrolling appears incomplete is because your image is still loading when you retrieve the body's scroll height, and by the time the image has loaded the body has already increased in height. This makes your old value stale, and hence you see that it is not scrolling all the way to the bottom.

The workaround is to **only perform the scrolling after the image is loaded**. This can be done by firing the scroll-to-bottom logic when:

- the image has fired the `load` event, or
- the image's `complete` property evaluates to true and has a non-zero natural width/height (mostly a fix for IE, which does not fire `load` event for images loaded from cache, [see better explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025364/395910))

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function createElement1() {

    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    
    // Scroll-to-bottom logic
    function scrollToBottom() {
      window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    
    // Attach load event listener
    x.addEventListener('load', function() {
      scrollToBottom();
    });
    
    // Fix for IE if loading image from cache
    if (x.complete && x.naturalWidth > 0) {
      scrollToBottom();
    }
    
    x.setAttribute("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400");
    x.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    x.setAttribute("height", "auto");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "img");
    document.getElementById("id").appendChild(x);

    
}

createElement1();
```

```css
#filler {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="filler">Just to take up space</div>
<div id="id">Image to be appended below<br /></div>
```

Comment: Really nice answer! I wasn't aware of the IE bug with `img.load`. I didn't see the IE version this applies up to in your linked answer, any ideas?

Comment: @MorganWilde I guess that works for all versions of IE :)