# How to check if picture is loaded?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a picture is already loaded?

```
image.src = ay.url_static + 'uploads/apps/' + thumbnail.uid + '.png';
image.onload = function(e)
{                   
    // [..]
};
```

I know how to trigger a callback upon image is loaded, but how do I check if picture is loaded at the moment?

Comment: @tybro0103, I could be. How would that help?

Comment: this post has some additional good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268557/what-workarounds-exist-for-the-complete-property-in-firefox

Comment: Why my question was down-voted two times? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but from what I understand you need to know if an image is loaded at any moment in time, right?

I've one function do check if the image is valid. You can use it to see if the image is already loaded also if you want. If you don't want to know if the image is valid, you can use only the img.complete property.

```
function IsImageLoaded(img) {

    if (!img.complete) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: haven't tested, but I've read .complete is buggy in Firefox, FYI

Comment: Really? I know firefox has a different behavior, the browser tries to download all images before the page start to load, so the event onload in the images does not fire as it should, but I never hear anything about the complete property. Can you show me your source?

Comment: This doesn't reply on the question the author asks for. Author asks how to check if <picture> is loaded, not <img>. 

I'm looking for solution also but can't find the right solution :) 
onload() method doesn't work with picture tags so how we can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Set `image.loaded = false`, and then set `image.loaded = true` in your onload callback and check that property later?

Or image.complete seems like a legit property, if not W3C.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using jQuery...

```
image.onload = function(e)
{                   
    $(this).data({loaded: true});
};
```

later...

```
if($(yourImage).data('loaded')) {
  // it's loaded!
} else {
  // it's not
}
```

jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is great for setting variables specific to elements.

Comment: Hm. This isn't exactly the same. Though, in my specific case this might be applied. Will hear what others have to say.

Comment: I agree. Bruno Costa's answer looks best.