# jquery image load event, dont work with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, load

i have a problem with loading images after changing their scr attribute. but this only doesn't work in firefox on mac. on pc i havn't tested yet.

the problem is, that the image get loaded, the function fires, fadein works, but shows the OLD image, 1-2s seconds later the new image will be shown. may be the load event dont work with images in firefox? its not a caching problem, i deleted browser cache every time.

this function get called with setTimeout every 2500ms, before this, in another function i do the same for initialization. same process, except of being faded out. the html has placeholderimages, which get new src attributes, then fade in, and all is good.

but in the change function it doesnt work..

```
// change photos
function changeImg(feed) {
  var images = $('#instafeed img'); 
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

  $(images.eq(rand)).fadeOut(500, function () {
    $(images.eq(rand))
    .one('load', function() { 
      $(this).fadeIn(500);
    })
    .attr("href", feed.data[bildIndex].link)
    .attr("src", feed.data[bildIndex].images.low_resolution.url);

    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
    bildIndex++;
    if (bildIndex == 14) bildIndex = 0;
  });                   
}
```

Comment: Does the fiddle that I posted in step 1 work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Some things I can suggest: -

1. Try to narrow the problem down. See **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s2ZA/1/)**. This works for me on Chrome and Firefox using on Windows (don't have a mac to try on). Does it work for you? If it does, then try to determine what is different about your code.
2. Try the imagesloaded wrapper. See [here](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded). It handles some of the cross-browser oddities with loading images and may help in your case.
3. Try appending a unique parameter to the src attribute to force the image not to be retrieved from the cache. For example `.attr("src", feed.data[bildIndex].images.low_resolution.url + "?" + new Date().getTime());`. Since the image does eventually get loaded, I am not sure it will help in your case.

I also noticed that you are setting an `href` on the image. I don't think that `href` is a valid attribute for an html img element.

For completeness, the jsfiddle code is:

HTML:

```
<img src ='origSrc'>
<button onclick='changePic();'>click me</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function changePic()
{
    var $theImage = $('img'); 

    $theImage.fadeOut(500, function () {
        $theImage.one('load', function() 
            { 
                $(this).fadeIn(499);     
            }
        )
        .attr("src","newSrc");    
        if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');    
  });  
}
```

From what we have discovered in the comments it appears that for Firefox `if(this.complete)` is always returning true. If you remove this line, then it works OK. This seems to be a known problem, take a look at the different options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268557/what-workarounds-exist-for-the-complete-property-in-firefox). The last resort is that you could clone, then remove the image and then fade in the new image where the old image was.

Comment: 1. no it don't work in latest firefox an mac. same problem. fade out. and when the fade-in begins, the old picture is shown for a short moment. forgot to say it: this problem occurs ONLY when the image aren't loaded yet. if they are, and iterate about 14 pictures, the script works fine!

Comment: with the href was my failure.. orignally there was a parent().attr()… :) but thats not the problem

Comment: 3. doesnt work. same problem. but it's definetly not a caching problem.

Comment: @zorstn - yes, as I mentioned, 3 was not likely the problem, just checking the box. The fact that 1 doesn't work is interesting as it works for me in Firefox on Windows, so I think you are right this seems to be a Firefox on mac strangeness.

Comment: ive tried your fiddle on win 7 firefox 22. the SAME problem occurs! but only if the image isn't cached!!

Comment: sorry i meant firefox 28, the latest.

Comment: hmm, I am using Firefox 28 as well and don't see it even when I clear cache. Strange.

Comment: @zorstn OK, I got it now. Will have a look.

Comment: @zorstn - if you remove `if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');` then it works for me. If think for Firefox it has not changed the this.complete value. You probably still needed for cached, but I think it is a clue.

Comment: @zorstn - I have updated my answer, take a look at the last paragraph and the reference question.

Comment: sure? when i remove it in my code, i have the same problem!? on mac and also win..  next i will try the clone method. thx

Comment: Hmm, that is really strange. I could get it to happen by adding a dummy arg at the end so that it reloaded, but when I commented the line it goes away. Did you press 'Run' on the jsfiddle after commenting the line to make sure that it was running with your change?

Comment: oh yes, the fiddle works :) but not in my projekt.. strange.
will try it again tomorrow.